# Log process id or name using iptables

Tags: iptables

I'm logging outgoing packets on my network. I want to log the process that created the outgoing packets.

I know I can match packets by [process id](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html#OWNERMATCH). And I know I can log the user id and group id of whatever generated the package.

But I want to log the process id. Is this possible with iptables?

Comment: There is no PID for much of the traffic you will receive.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/34782/with-linux-iptables-is-it-possible-to-log-the-process-command-name-that-initiat#34783